# bash: compare 2 files, then output third file with same pattern

Tags: bash, compare

So here is my problem: I have 2 files:

File a:

```
Username    ID  ChanelName
somename    1   Ime1
somename    6   Ime2
somename    16  Ime3
somename    12  Ime4
somename    19  Ime5
```

File b:

```
ID  subID   SubAccountName
1   12001   SubName1
1   12003   SubName2
2   17507   SubName3
3   11997   SubName4
4   345 SubName5
5   6457    SubName6
6   8567    SubName7
6   6456    SubName8
6   3453    SubName9
6   7453    SubName10
10  745 SubName11
11  63453   SubName12
12  5674    SubName13
13  74756   SubName14
14  2324    SubName15
15  6576    SubName16
16  7897    SubName17
16  980 SubName18
18  6786    SubName19
19  79089   SubName20
20  75674   SubName21
```

I want compare this files and output this result:

```
1   12001   SubName1
1   12003   SubName2
6   8567    SubName7
6   6456    SubName8
6   3453    SubName9
6   7453    SubName10
16  7897    SubName17
12  5674    SubName13
19  79089   SubName20
20  75674   SubName21
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

awk one liner

`awk '{if(NR>1)system("grep -w ^"$2" <file2>");}' <file1>`

Also many other solutions are there, check `join` or in `awk` itself without using `grep`, simply by storing the first files content in an array, it can be done,

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -n+2 file1 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -I{} grep '^{} ' file2
```